# Рассчитать координаты точки, зная координаты трех других и расстояние

Tags: javascript

Суть задания в следующем: в произвольной точке взрывается бомба, взрывная волна распространяется со скоростью 1 клетка в секунду. Зеленые точки - это датчики, которые фиксируют время попадания в зону поражения. Необходимо рассчитать координаты точки взрыва, зная координаты датчиков и расстояния от эпицентра до датчиков. Функция getBombCoordinates() на данный момент только считает расстояния.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

let w = canvas.width = 400
let h = canvas.height = 400
let colNum = 50
let rowNum = 50

let cell_w = w / colNum
let cell_h = h / rowNum

let isExploding = false

let probeTime1 = 0
let probeTime2 = 0
let probeTime3 = 0

let button = document.getElementById("button")
button.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Результат: " + getBombCoordinates(probeTime1,probeTime2,probeTime3)
}
canvas.addEventListener('click', setBomb)
drawNet()
function drawNet() {
    for (let x = 0; x < w +1; x += 8) {
        ctx.moveTo(x, 0)
        ctx.lineTo(x, 400)
    }
    for (let y = 0; y < h+1; y += 8) {
        ctx.moveTo(0, y)
        ctx.lineTo(400, y)
    }

    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.beginPath()
}

function explode(x, y, blowRadius) {

    isExploding = true

    let probe1 = ctx.getImageData(128, 32, 8, 8).data
    let probe2 = ctx.getImageData(80, 336, 8, 8).data
    let probe3 = ctx.getImageData(344, 296, 8, 8).data

    let top_left = ctx.getImageData(1, 1, 1, 1).data
    let top_right = ctx.getImageData(399, 1, 1, 1).data
    let bot_left = ctx.getImageData(1, 399, 1, 1).data
    let bot_right = ctx.getImageData(399, 399, 1, 1).data


    ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
    ctx.arc(x, y, blowRadius, 0, getRadians(360))
    ctx.fill()

    function getRadians(degrees) {
        return (Math.PI / 180) * degrees
    }
    if(probe1[0] !== 255){
        probeTime1++
        }

    if(probe2[0] !== 255){
        probeTime2++
    }
    if(probe3[0] !== 255){
        probeTime3++
    }

    if((top_left[0] !== 255) || (top_right[0] !== 255) || (bot_left[0] !== 255) || (bot_right[0] !== 255))  {

        blowRadius += 4
        setTimeout(() => explode(x, y, blowRadius), 1000)

    } else {
        isExploding = false
        setTimeout(() => {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)
            ctx.beginPath()
            drawNet()
        }, 2000)
    }

}
function setBomb(e) {
    probeTime1 = 0
    probeTime2 = 0
    probeTime3 = 0
    if (!isExploding) {
        let x = e.offsetX
        let y = e.offsetY
        let c_x = Math.floor(x / cell_w)
        let c_y = Math.floor(y / cell_h)
        let f_x = c_x * cell_w + 4
        let f_y = c_y * cell_h + 4
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)

        ctx.beginPath()
        drawNet()
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green'
        ctx.fillRect(128, 32, 8, 8)
        ctx.fillRect(80, 336, 8, 8)
        ctx.fillRect(344, 296, 8, 8)

        console.log(c_x)
        console.log(c_y)

        explode(f_x, f_y, 4)

    }
}
function getBombCoordinates(probeTime1,probeTime2, probeTime3){
    let distance1 = probeTime1 * 0.5

    let distance2 = probeTime2 * 0.5

    let distance3 = probeTime3 * 0.5

    let probe1X = Math.floor(128 / cell_w)
    let probe1Y = Math.floor(32 / cell_h)
    let probe2X = Math.floor(80 / cell_w)
    let probe2Y = Math.floor(336 / cell_h)
    let probe3X = Math.floor(344 / cell_w)
    let probe3Y = Math.floor(296 / cell_h)
    let distance = [distance1,distance2,distance3,probe1X,probe1Y,probe2X,probe2Y,probe3X,probe3Y]
    return distance

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вам известны расстояния, то берёте два датчика `А` и `B`, находите расстояние между ними `L`, вектор направления `AB = B-A = (B.x-A.x, B.y-A.y)`, нормализуете его `uAB = AB/L` и находите перпендикулярный единичный вектор `p = (-uAB.y, uAB.x)` - всё это делается один раз для заданного расположения датчиков.

Затем считаете для расстояний от взрыва до датчиков `dA, dB`:

```
t = (dA^2 - dB^2 + L^2) / (2*L)
u = sqrt(dA^2 - t^2)
```

И находите две возможные точки

```
P1 = A + uAB*t + p*u
P2 = A + uAB*t - p*u
```

И узнаёте, какая подходит, проверив расстояние до датчика C

([описано в вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True-range_multilateration#Two_Cartesian_dimensions,_two_measured_slant_ranges_(Trilateration)) для расположения датчиков в нуле и на оси OX)

Для справки код на Python, пяток примеров вычислений на валидных данных, картинки для второго и последнего расположений

```
import math
def explo(ax,ay,bx,by,cx,cy,da,db,dc):
    abx = bx - ax
    aby = by - ay
    l = math.hypot(abx, aby)
    #Здесь предусмотреть случаи if da + db < L и т.д.
    abx /= l
    aby /= l
    nx = -aby
    ny = abx
    t = 0.5*(da*da - db*db + l*l)/l
    u = math.sqrt(da*da - t*t)
    px = ax + abx * t + nx * u
    py = ay + aby * t + ny * u
    if abs(math.hypot(px-cx, py-cy)  - dc) < 0.1:
        return [px, py]
    px = ax + abx * t - nx * u
    py = ay + aby * t - ny * u
    if abs(math.hypot(px-cx, py-cy)  - dc) < 0.1:
        return [px, py]

print(explo(0, 0, 10, 0, 4, 7, 4, 6, 7))
print(explo(1, 1, 8, 1, 3, 8, 5.83, 6.4, 2.24))
print(explo(1, 1, 8, 1, 3, 8, 6.71, 3.16, 10.77))
print(explo(1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 8, 6.71, 7.28, 10.77))
print(explo(10, 8, 5, 5, 12, 2, 10.44, 7.28, 6.4))

[4.0, 0.0]
[4.002064285714285, 5.997650450405549]
[7.00275, -1.998515038731672]
[7.002409363885446, -1.9991968638854467]
[7.0003512133137935, -1.9997853555229836]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если же известны не расстояния, а относительные времена срабатывания при неизвестном времени взрыва, то придётся считать настоящую трилатерацию, как я описывал [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36176999/844416)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то если у нас есть расстояния, то бомба будет находиться в месте пересечения трех окружностей с центрами в датчиках и радиусами в эти расстояния. Если же времени начала распространения взрывной волны у нас нет, то нет и расстояний. Но есть дельты расстояний относительно первого затронутого датчика. И тогда бомбу можно найти увеличивая все радиусы на шаг пока все три окружности не сойдутся в одной точке. То есть можно применить бинарный поиск для решения этой задачи. А как найти математически эту точку пересечения окружностей? Интересная задача))

Comment: @Leonid искать точку пересечения двух окружностей и сверять с третьей. Или искать точки пересечения (1 и 2) и (1 и 3) и смотреть расстояние между ними (точек пересечения по две, может быть громоздко). Однако итеративный метод не обязательно применять, можно сразу рассчитать, как по второй ссылке показано

Comment: @MBo Я пытался решить задачу Вашим методом, но получаю две неправильные точки. Помогите пожалуйста написать код вашего решения, мне кажется я просто неправильно прописал эти формулы.

Comment: @КириллКриницкий, вы же даже не ответили на вопрос известны ли расстояния, то есть определено ли время, прошедшее с момента начала взрыва. За вас додумали и ответили на два отдельных вопроса сразу. И тут же, не вникая, просите написать код. Определитесь с условиями, расчертите схему, перейдите по ссылкам и изучите вопрос, а там все будет понятно. В конце концов у вас куча ненужных данных. Надо всего лишь три координаты для каждого датчика и время прошедшее либо с момента взрыва, либо с касания первого датчика до момента касания каждого датчика в отдельности. Что на вход и что на выход.